# Delete all lines upto some regex match

Tags: regex, vim

I want to delete everything from start of the document upto some regex match, such as `_tmm`. I wrote the following custom command:

```
command! FilterTmm exe 'g/^_tmm\\>/,/^$/mo$' | norm /_tmm<CR> | :0,-1 d
```

This doesn't work as expected. But when I execute these commands directly using the command line, they work.

Do you have any alternative suggestions to accomplish this job using custom commands?

Comment: I don't know about vimscript, but this is simply `ggV/_tmm<CR>d`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to remove from beginning to the line above the matched line.

`/pattern` could have offset option. like `/pattern/{offset}`, `:h /` for detail, for your needs, you could do (no matter where your cursor is):

```
ggd/_tmm/-1<cr>
```

**EDIT**

I read your question twice, it seems that you want to do it in a single command line.

Your script has problem, `normal` doesn't support `|`, that is, it must be the last command.

try this line, if it works for you:

```
exe 'norm gg'|/_tmm/-1|0,.d
```